# How to launch MSTest and run a command from batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt, mstest

I'm making a batch file in order to build all my solutions and then run my all my unit tests located in a dll previously built.

I'm trying to make something similar to

```
start "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\mstest.exe"  MSTest /testcontainer:tests.dll
```

to launch MSTest.exe and run "MSTest /testcontainer:tests.dll" command inside MSTest command line, but this doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out with that? Thanks.

Comment: Try with `start "" "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\mstest.exe"  MSTest /testcontainer:tests.dll` because the `start` command might interprete the `.exe` file path as a window title as it is the first quoted argument...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It worked but still doesn't solve the problem. Now, MSTest.exe starts but the command doesn't do anything. It looks like being executed before all components from cmd loads because the welcome message wasn't shown.

Comment: Why do you have the extra MSTest parameter in there?  Also, you should only use `mstest.exe` if you are supporting legacy VS2010 projects.  Otherwise, you should be using `vstest.console.exe`.

Comment: Removing MSTest and removing start made it work. I only had a MSTest parameters because in MSTest.exe worked with this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem,

I had to run without `start` and `MSTest` flags, as example:

```
"%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\mstest.exe"  /testcontainer:tests.dll
```

Thank you for all who helped.

Comment: This helped me.  If the test dll is in a sub folder, add the path like this:

"%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\mstest.exe"  /testcontainer:myTestProject\bin\Debug\myTestProject.dll